# Dealing with or casting an object returned from method.invoke() when using reflection

Tags: java, exception, object, reflection, casting

Using Java, I have a method which I'm calling with method.invoke that returns a string.
Method.invoke returns an object though which can't be cast to String.
How am I supposed to use the Object as a string??

In the docs on reflection it shows the following:

```
Object o = m.invoke(t, new Locale(args[1], args[2], args[3]));
out.format("%s() returned %b%n", mname, (Boolean) o);
```

But my code does this and I get an exception: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String

This is an abstract class - there will then be several implementations of beans.

```
            Method[] methods = this.getClass().getMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (isMethodGetter(method)) {
            
            try {

                Object message = method.invoke(this); // expect a string    
                       Object message = method.invoke(this); // expect a string
                
                if (message == null) {
                    // no messeage
                } else {
                    logger.debug("Calling listAnswers: got an answer: "
                            + message);

                    // create an answer object from the reflected
                    Answer answer = new Answer();
                    answer.setText((String)message);//cast as string
                    answerList.add(answer);
        }
```

edit: as per below answers I had a problem with the validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple: you didn't get an instance of `java.lang.String`, but of `java.lang.Class`. Your clarification in the comment makes it all crystal-clear: the method `java.lang.Object.getClass` passes your `isMethodGetter` test, but it's not want you wanted. Just enhance that checking code to not let the exact name `getClass` pass.

Comment: Nothing special but I'll edit the question for anyone else who has this issue... Maybe I'm doing something funny :) Method[] methods = this.getClass().getMethods();
  for (Method method : methods) {
   if (isMethodGetter(method)) {
    
    try {

     Object message = method.invoke(this); // expect a string

Comment: yep you are 100% correct. I checked the log and noticed that indeed the getClass is showing up in the debug DEBUG [com.prevacidecrm.questionaire.model.Questionaire listAnswers] = Calling listAnswers: got an answer: class com.prevacidecrm.questionaire.model.impl.PerksEntryQuestionaire. Amazing - thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you get a ClassCastException then you need to check if in fact you're calling the right method. But to be helpful, if in fact you're expecting a string, maybe yo can call the toString() method if the returned object is not null.

Comment: This is what I did and it works. I would be interested in seeing how to properly do this if another type was expected though.

Comment: @JasonG Read my updated answer. Your situation is crystal-clear and easy to fix.